# Как исправить ошибку вывода элементов массива в цикле for?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется следующий код:

```
let ruLabels = ["часов", "минут", "секунд"],
       label = $('.flipclock-label');

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < ruLabels.length; j++) {
        label.text(ruLabels[j]);
    }
}
```

Необходимо заменить текст каждого из элементов `.flipclock-label` соответствующим элементом массива `ruLabels`. Вместо этого текст заменяется только третьим элементом массива, то есть `"секунд"`.

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь для этого методом `each`

```js
const ruLabels = ["часов", "минут", "секунд"];

$('.flipclock-label').each((index, label) => {
  $(label).text(ruLabels[index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="flipclock-label"></span>
<span class="flipclock-label"></span>
<span class="flipclock-label"></span>
```

Comment: [`each` не нужен](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function): `$('.flipclock-label').text(i=>ruLabels[i])`

Answer (score 4):

Можно так:

```js
const ruLabels = ["часов", "минут", "секунд"],
  labels = $('.flipclock-label').toArray();

labels.forEach((el, i) => {
  $(el).text(ruLabels[i]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="flipclock-label">One</span>
<span class="flipclock-label">Two</span>
<span class="flipclock-label">Three</span>
```

P.S. Пока писал сниппет уже ответили схожей реализацией)) Но оставлю, пусть будет...

Answer (score 3):

Пример на чистом JS

```js
let ruLabels = ["часов", "минут", "секунд"],
  label = document.querySelectorAll('.flipclock-label');

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  label[i].innerHTML = ruLabels[i];
}
```

```html
<span class="flipclock-label">One</span>
<span class="flipclock-label">Two</span>
<span class="flipclock-label">Three</span>
```

вариант два

```js
["часов", "минут", "секунд"].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.flipclock-label')[i].innerHTML = arr[i];
})
```

```html
<span class="flipclock-label">One</span>
<span class="flipclock-label">Two</span>
<span class="flipclock-label">Three</span>
```